# Genexus y Dockers

Tags: genexus

Estamos empezando a ver este tema de Dockers con Gx.
Ya tengo el Docker local andando con Windows 10 y adentro su tomcat operativo el cual accedo desde mi maquina local  (http://localhost:8081).

Ahora lo que quisiera es que al compilar mi aplicación las clases compiladas fueran directamente al directorio /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/appjavaenviroment  del docker.

O sea que el servlet directory fuera del tomcat del docker mismo y no el de mi PC.

Hay forma de hacer eso?
O siempre hay que desarrollar en el tomcat local?

Saludos y gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: pero si haces eso cuando reinicies la instancia docker perderas toda la info, precisamente por eso se hace que se vincule a una carpeta local de pc. puedes usar ` docker run -p 8081:8080 -v /ruta/local/a/tu/app:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/appjavaenviroment tomcat ` reemplaza /ruta/local/a/tu/app con la ruta local de tu aplicación en tu equipo

Comment: Hola John, Gracias por tu comentario. Yo entendía que un docker era como una maquina virtual, donde pongo "cosas adentro" y voy trabajando con ellas. Me parece que necesito mas información para comenzar este tema. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: es mas simple ver a docker como una maquina virtual de java donde corre algo que tienes en tu maquina, o como un programa que usa tu informacion pero no deberias almacenar informacion en ella a menos que quieras desplegar muchas instancias con tu código ya precompilado pero eso es otro tema.

Comment: Claro, pero yo en VirtualBox tiro archivos y aplicaciones para adentro de la maquina, luego la apago, la prendo, la llevo en un pendrive, etc. Y siempre esta todo ahí. Mi idea de los contendores era esa.

Comment: la idea es que un contenedor te siba para desarrollar y para ponser en produccion, puedes modificar y dejar tu codigo en el contenedor pero para eso debes hacer una version con todo dentro, buca como colocar mis archivos dentro de un contenerot y despues como hacer un comit de un contenedor modificado, con eso puedes, o bien puede usar docker-compose para evitar estar modificando el contendor a cada instante.